# Ionic 3 using IonPage with DeepLinkMetadataType on tabs - getting rid of tab-0

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a page with some tabs that are lazy loaded:

explore.html

```
<ion-tabs>
   <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" [tabTitle]="hotTitle" tabIcon="flame"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" [tabTitle]="searchTitle" tabIcon="search"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" [tabTitle]="mapTitle" tabIcon="map"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

@IonicPage({
  segment: 'explore',
  defaultHistory: ['HomePage']
})
```

The page behind tab1Root has an IonPage decorator like this

```
@IonicPage({
  segment: 'hot-channels',
  defaultHistory: ['HomePage']
})
```

However when navigating to the hot-channels-page, the url shows:
http://localhost:8100/#/explore/tab-0/hot-channels

Where does the "tab-0" come from? It seems unnecessary, and in the docs there is nothing mentioned about it. Any chance to get rid of that and go directly with something like http://localhost:8100/#/explore/hot-channels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some solution if someone else is interested. Even though it might not be possible to erase the tab url completetly, at least we can modify the name.
In each tab you can make use of the tabUrlPath attribute to specify the url:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabUrlPath="my-tab-name" [tabTitle]="hotTitle" tabIcon="flame"></ion-tab>
 [...]
</ion-tabs>
```

This would result in:
http://localhost:8100/#/explore/my-tab-name/hot-channels

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tab/#input-properties